# display online users only when isAdmin is true

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am creating an online chat application with Spring Boot application. I am able to display all the online users with the following code

**Code snippets from my UserDao.java class**

```
public List getAll() {
    return getSession().createQuery("from User").list();
}
```

**Controller calling the UserDao.java method for retrieving all**

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/get-all-users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        try {
            return _userDao.getAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception in fetching users: ", e.getStackTrace());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

is there a way I can display all the users only when is admin is set to true.

**Users.java bean class**

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long timestamp;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private boolean isAdmin;

    public User() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }

        if (this.id == null || obj == null || !(this.getClass().equals(obj.getClass()))) {
            return false;
        }

        User that = (User) obj;

        return this.id.equals(that.getId());
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id == null ? 0 : id.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return isAdmin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(boolean isAdmin) {
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
    }
```

Please how can I retrieve all the Users only when isAdmin is set to true instead of just displaying all the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be possible with

```
public List getAll() {
    return getSession().createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.isAdmin = true").list();
}
```

Disclaimer: Didn't check the code.